# why can there be a service in the module constructor undefined?

Tags: angular, angular11, ng-modules

I have a singleton module that has a forRoot method that returns a ModuleWithProviders object in which a service is specified in the providers array that is used in the constructor of the same module.
The module and the service are exported by the angular library (they are located in projects).

```js
@Injectable()
class SomeService {
    setValue(v) {/*...*/}
}


@NgModule({})
export class SomeModule {
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SomeModule> {
        // when debagging SomeService here exists as class
        return {
            ngModule: SomeModule,
            providers: [SomeService],
        };
    }

    constructor(
        private service: SomeService,
        @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule?: SomeModule,
    ) {
        // but here service === undefined
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error(
                'SomeModule already uploaded. Import it only from AppModule',
            );
        } else {
            service.setValue('value');
        }
    }
}
```

SomeModule  is imported into the app-module as follows:

```js
//...
imports: [SomeModule.forRoot()]
//...
```

Why provided service in constructor can be undefined?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're trying to accomplish, but generally modules should be linked _before_ the app starts. I have never seen used the constructor of a module, but I think the module cannot have itself dependencies injected. You could provide "something else" and use a factory function that uses the service, but its not clear what you want.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Modules can inject own providers. And what I have described usually works. It is unclear to me how to find out what may be the reason for the" loss " of the service.

Comment: If by _"usually"_ you mean in components or services, I agree: it works. But dependency injection at the module level, performed _before_ the module has been registered, doesn't make sense to me. I suspect it is used only to support the "module loaded more than once" guard pattern.

Comment: Try using `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` I only check the faIconLibrary in github that is defined in this way